# How can a script know whether a user can input or not?

Tags: bash, user-input

Is there a way a bash script (or whatever language) can determine whether its being run in a headless way? I want to know whether a user can input or not. If they can, I am going to ask them something.

Comment: You can check for a connected tty with the `-t` flag to `[`/`test`.

Comment: How is this too broad?

Comment: "bash script (or whatever language)" is pretty broad. Also "headless way" is pretty broad without further clarification. That said I think the answer (for bash) is pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From **man bash**:

```
An  interactive  shell  is  one  started without non-option arguments and without the -c option whose standard input and
       error are both connected to terminals (as determined by isatty(3)), or one started with the -i option.  PS1 is  set  and
       $- includes i if bash is interactive, allowing a shell script or a startup file to test this state.
```